# Cakephp CSS file not loading

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a website working on one server. I am changing hosting, so I created a website on another server for testing.

Everything seems to be working, except CSS. It is not loading at all. I have 777 for tmp folder and mod re_write enabled.

I can see all cached files except for CSS.

Please advise and help

This is my .htacess file  in www

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

This is my second htaccess inside  app

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

This is my third htaccess inside  webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and the url is 23.236.49.24

Comment: The CSS file is in the app/webroot folder, right? Can you access any other file that's in the webroot folder? Images, XML, anything...

Comment: i cant access anything from webroot

Comment: No code, no explanation ("_not loading at all_", "_I can see all cached files_", that could mean anything), no debugging attempts, no environment/version information - how should anyone here be able to answer your question without asking hundreds of things first? SO is not ment as a debugging service, that's what you should do _before_ asking questions. That being said, as a first step check your [**rewrite logs**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

Comment: @user3811984 sounds like a mod_rewrite issue... Like ndm says, could you post as much information as possible about your set up? What CakePHP version are you running? How do your URLs look like? How do the .htaccess files look like?

Comment: This is my .htacess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/app/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
and the url is http://23.236.49.24/

Comment: @user3811984 first of all, it's better to post code using the `code` formatting, it makes it easier. Also, it would be better in this case to edit the question and add that information there. I tried your website and none of the links (that aren't javascript) seem to work, so there's definitely something going in with mod_rewrite. Could you post (in your question) the contents of the 3 .htaccess files that your cake installation has?

Comment: Do u have CSS inside webroot , css?

Comment: hav U uploaded htaccess? Goto firezilla see hidden files, is htaccess there on server ?  i think no. press Ctrl+f5

Comment: yes its there i have uploaded .htacess plus css is inside webroot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line:

`RewriteBase /`

under

`RewriteEngine On`

in the 3 .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file in webroot folder.
And paste this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```