# Cakephp css,images and subpages are not loading

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, web-config

My website(http://www.mytripkerala.com/) which is built in cakephp works well in old server.When i changed it to my new server the homepage is loading without style and images.And all subpage links showing 404 error.My htaccess files are

htaccess inside webroot

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess inside app folder

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess outside app folder

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me to solve the problem..

Comment: Please check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311667/cakephp-css-file-not-loading

Comment: see the following post. its may be simpler prob with your prob, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616389/remove-index-php-from-url-in-cakephp-2-6-x-in-ubuntu